# Bash Redirection Not Working with Rscript

Tags: bash, rscript

I'm writing a series of jobs where output needs to be stored in centralised log file. And im using standard redirection command in unix &> for redirecting stdout to file.

But this statement is not redirecting the logs to a file for Rscript command. Its working for all other python, sas and jupyter jobs.

`Rscript /notebooks/notebooks/Rsamplemode.R &> /out/store.log`

Nothing is getting written to file /out/store.log but instead its printing to stdout

[image]

I have done whoami and im currently the root user.

Comment: I assume that you do not use `bash`.

Comment: its a shell inside kubernetes pod. I used echo $SHELL to check which shell it is and it returned blank.

Comment: this command usually gets executed from kubernetes  spec    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      <<commands here>>

Comment: If it's sh, `&>` won't work.

Comment: `sh` doesn't understand `&>` (Which in bash and some other shells, redirects both standard output and standard error)

Answer (score 0):

try with tee:

```sh
Rscript /notebooks/notebooks/Rsamplemode.R 2>&1 | tee /out/store.log
```